# Deserialize XML into object with dynamic child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to deserialize some xml into a C# object. The trick is for the most part, I know what this object will look like. However, this is one child that has dynamic elements.

(here is an example)

```
<measurement>
  <Time>2021-02-02</Time>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <LeftWheel>
  <ValuesRead>
    <DynamicValue>12.3</DynamicValue>
    <DynamicValue2>2.3</DynamicValue2>
    <DynamicValue4>1.3</DynamicValue4>
    <DynamicValue3>10.3</DynamicValue3>
  </ValuesRead>
  </LeftWheel>
      <RightWheel>
  <ValuesRead>
    <DynamicValue>12.3</DynamicValue>
    <DynamicValue2>2.3</DynamicValue2>
    <DynamicValue6>1.3</DynamicValue6>
    <DynamicValue10>10.3</DynamicValue10>
  </ValuesRead>
  </RightWheel>
</measurement>
```

In this XML, `Measurement`, `Time`, and `ID` are always going to in the object.
The `LeftWheel` and `RightWheel` elements are always going to be there with `ValuesRead`, but the `ValuesRead` children are dynamic and can be anything.

I have tried making a C# object to reflect most the structure, and then using the `XmlSerializer.UnknownElement` to pick up the unknown elements in the `ValuesRead` element, but I cannot link it to the parent above to know if it is on the `LeftWheel` or `RightWheel`.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FVISSiteEvent));

serializer.UnknownElement += UnknownElementFound;
```

Is there a way I can define the `LeftWheel` and `RightWheel` classes to be dynamic for the serialization, while having the other classes not dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this using a dynamic type when deserializing.
When I deserialize `ValuesRead`, it is a defined as a dynamic type.

When deserialized, it turns into an `XmlNode` and from there I iterate over the node use the `Name` and `InnerText` values to read all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `UnknownElementFound` event to manually handle these aspects of serialization. See: [Serialize XML array of unknown element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734911/serialize-xml-array-of-unknown-element-name)

Other options could be to specify the types you expect to see as `XmlElementAtrribute` decorated properties and they will just be null if they aren’t deserialized.

There’s also the nuclear option of implementing `IXmlSerializable` in your class and taking full control of the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Uses Custom Serializer :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Measurement));
            Measurement measurement = (Measurement)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME,settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, measurement);
 
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("measurement")]
    public class Measurement
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("LeftWheel")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ValuesRead")]
        public List<Wheel> leftWheel { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("RightWheel")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ValuesRead")]
        public List<Wheel> rightWheel { get; set; }
    }
    public class Wheel : IXmlSerializable
    {
        List<decimal> values { get; set; }

        // Xml Serialization Infrastructure

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            int count = 0;
            XElement valuesRead = new XElement("ValuesRead");
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++ )
            {
                valuesRead.Add(new XElement("ValuesRead" + (i == 0? "" : i.ToString()), values[i]));
            }
            writer.WriteRaw(valuesRead.ToString());

        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            XElement values = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
            this.values = values.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("DynamicValue")).Select(x => (decimal)x).ToList(); 
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }


        
    } 
}
```